# Adding and retrieving metadata from Ember routes

Tags: ember.js

For reporting purposes, I want to associate some metadata with an Ember route, and would prefer to do it as follows:

```
this.route('list', { path: '/list', description: 'Master List' });
```

then access this `description` property from places like the route itself, or from elsewhere, such as the `didTransition` hook on the application router. I've reviewed the source for Router and Route and cannot say I really understand it, certainly not well enough to understand how to retrieve custom properties specified in this way. I see there is an object called DSL, which is apparently the `this` of the `this.route` specified in the `map` method on `Router`, but cannot see how to get from here to there. From within a subclass of `Ember.Route`, I see properties called `this.router`, and `this.router.router`, but am unclear on what these point to.

Or, the following would also work if that allowed me to do what I wanted:

```
this.route('list', { path: '/list' }, function() {
    this.description = "Master List";
});
```

Can I associate custom properties with a route specified in `Router#map`, and if so how?

Comment: I can see you've attempted to go through the source code to try work it out - so I take it you're comfortable extending/modifying the default implementations of Ember.Router/Ember.Route and implementing your own versions of the EmberDSL - which would be implementing/altering a lot of private APIs - to get the end goal you're after. You would have to keep your implementations up to date with changes in Ember - always making sure yours worked when you upgraded.. Is this something you're willing to do to get the outcome you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this along the following lines, writing my own "route" function which records data I need, then passes it along to the DSL:

```
var myRouteData = {};

function route(dsl, name, options, fn) {
  if (typeof options === 'function') fn = options, options = {};
  var routeName = dsl.parent ? dsl.parent + '.' + name : name;
  myRouteData[routeName] = { options.myRouteOption };

  dsl.route(name, options.fn);
}
```

Usage:

```
this.resource('foo', function() {
  route(this, 'bar', {myRouteOption: true});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be an elegant way to set metadata about a route when it is defined in the router, but maybe try this ugly solution within your  application controller:

```
currentPathChange: function () {
  switch(this.get('currentPath')){
    case 'test.index':
      console.log('test.index is the foo!');
      break;
    case 'test.new':
      console.log('test.new is the bar!');
      break;
  }
}.observes('currentPath')
```

[JSBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qeyeve/3/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Without extending Ember's Router, one option is to have a separate object that maintains route metadata. Simple example:

```
this.route('list', { path: '/list' });
routeMetaData['list'] = 'Master List';
```

To access the metadata in the `didTransition` hook:

```
didTransition: function() {
    var metadata = routeMetaData[this.routeName];
}
```